# What is a good introductory book to linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am currently a high-school sophomore taking AP Calculus AB, and I am doing well. I also love mathematics and want to learn more about what is to come. I am looking for a good introductory text to linear algebra, something similar to the calculus book *A Tour of the Calculus* by David Berlinski, which I read before taking calculus. I am not going to rigorously study anything (do problem sets, etc.) but I am looking for something that has a good blend of theoretical elements and practical techniques. Any recommendations? I am considering *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang and *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler.

Comment: The two books you mentioned are good. You might also take a look at [Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra -- Vectors, Matrices, and Least Squares](http://vmls-book.stanford.edu/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senior in the department recommends These three.

1. Contemporary Linear Algebra (Anton, Busby)
2. Introduction to Linear Algebra (Strang)
3. Linear Algebra (Lang)